# solving coupled non linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve a set of non linear differential equations. I have generated the equations by this:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 2, j++,
  For[k = 1, k <= 2, k++,
   Print[I D[M1'[[i]][[j]][[k]], t] == 
     Part[(m2/((*b[[i]]*)10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
          10^5/t^4*Sum[If[l == i, 0, M1'[[l]]], {l, 1, 3, 1}]).M1'[[
         i]] - M1'[[
         i]].(m2/((*b[[i]]*)10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
          10^5/t^4*Sum[If[l == i, 0, M1'[[l]]], {l, 1, 3, 1}]), j, 
      k]]]]]
```

where ,

```
M1' = Table[
  Array[Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
```

Now I am not finding a way as to how to solve these equations by NDSolve. Please suggest me something about this.

Comment: To solve an ODE you need initial conditions. Further, you must not print the equations, but create a list of them that you can then feed to DSolve or NDSolve. And do not use names containing an apostrophe, this will lead to trouble. Further, m2 has no value.

Comment: Thank you. But how to make the list? Also I forgot to add m2   ,                                  \[Theta] =(*34.5*)11.53*\[Pi]/180(*0.001*);
m2 = 1/(2*2)*2*10^-3*{{Cos[
     2 \[Theta]], -Sin[2 \[Theta]]}, {-Sin[2 \[Theta]], -Cos[
      2 \[Theta]]}}

Comment: Instead of: For[For[For...,Print[.. use equations= Table[ your code ,{i,1,3},{j,1,2},{k,1,2}]. And post corrected code..